# Facebook api: show dialog window for the user select page (manage_pages extendend perm)

Tags: php, javascript, api, facebook, permissions

I want ny users to give ny app "manage_pages" extended pemission but i want my users to be able to select which of their pages they give permission to.

I have this code which is responsible to autenticate and get the users permissions:

```
 $('#btn-connect-facebook').click(function(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            if (response.perms) {
               -> //new popup window for select which page it gives permissions//
               //window.location = (...) // redirect to php page
            } else {
              alert("You need to grant the required permissions");
            }
        } else {
            alert("There was an error connecting to facebook");
        }
    }, {perms:'manage_pages,publish_stream,read_stream,create_event,offline_access'});
});
```

How should i suppose to make the user choose which page he wants to give permissions?.
I have tried add enable_profile_selector but it messes up with my perms (the dialog dont request all the needed permissions.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only permission a user can give a page is the `publish_stream` permission. All other permissions are user permissions. E.g., they are not selectable / customizable for pages.
The `manage_pages` permission is an all or nothing permission. Either the user allows (all) pages access or none by giving this permission to an application.