# How to get Manage Pages permission to a particular facebook page or app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Is it possible to get permission to access particular page/app using Manage Pages Permissions?

Ex: A third party application requires access to a user's page. Using "Manage_Pages"
gives access to all the pages and apps that user has created/installed. How can I just ask Mange_Pages permission for particular page?

Below related questions found on SO but none of them gave the answer.

1. [how to set manage_pages permission to a particular facebook page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769664/how-to-set-manage-pages-permission-to-a-particular-facebook-page)
2. [Facebook api: show dialog window for the user select page (manage_pages extendend perm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397716/facebook-api-show-dialog-window-for-the-user-select-page-manage-pages-extenden)

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to limit the scope of these permissions?

Comment: @Connor, Because the user does not like to give access to all of his/her pages.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible with the API. You can control the scope of your changes to just one page client-side, but there's no way to get a list of pages without manage_pages permission. Once you have the permission, you can use the page access token to make changes to individual pages. See the `accounts` connection under `Users` for more info https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/